# Is there a way to move the curve vertex on the mesh surface?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I drew a few curves on the surface of the mesh. Keeping the curve vertex on the mesh surface while moving it is challenging.
Is there a way to constrain the curve vertex on the mesh surface?

Comment: You can use the snap tool (snap to faces option)

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific? I don't know what exact it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the *Snap (Face Project)* option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I used this method and the process became smoothly.